# Aphabetical search element

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have a search field but always when I search for a name it always starts from the top how can I make sure its aphabetical, according to the first letter the user inputs. Here is my model code below

```
public function getName($id)
    {
        $select = $this ->select()
                        ->where('service_provider_id  = ?', $id)
                        ->order('service_provider_name ASC')
                        ->limit(20);

        return $this->fetchRow($select);
    }
```

Comment: You are searching by id first and ordering by another column,fetchrow () returns only one raw if the condition is met. So your desired ouptput will not be achieved by using this function. Need to change it .

Comment: But then how come when I try to type a name by maybe Z letter it autocompletes from the 1 field in the table instead of showing all the z fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    $select = $this ->select()
                    ->where('service_provider_id  = ?', $id)
                    ->where('service_provider_name LIKE \'%' . $first_letter . '\'')
                    ->order('service_provider_name ASC')
                    ->limit(20);
```

Comment: Im still getting the same results

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would do this as:

```
order by (case when service_provider_name >= 'F' then 0 else 1 end),
         service_provider_name
```

You would put in the appropriate letter where `'F'` is.

This is standard SQL and should run on all engines.  Perhaps the same approach will work in the Zend framework.

Comment: I already have the element its not working properly, how can edit it to work the way I want it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are searching by name. So you need to change your code accordingly.
What you want achieve and the function in your model are not inline.
For Example,   `return $this->fetchRow($select);` will return back the only matched raw in the table and again you are doing  `->limit(20)` What are you limiting here. The result from the function will always be either 1 raw or none and the same goes  to order. 
As I think you want search By name considering the first input letter and order the result, limit it to 20.
Try to change you Method to this:-

```
public function searchByName() 
{
  $select = $this ->select();  
  $select    ->where('service_provider_name LIKE ?', '%'.$service_provider_name)
             ->order('service_provider_name ASC')
              ->limit(0,20);


        return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```